# Float issue with smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am trying to figure out the best approach to have a link with an image floated next to it inline, that will force the link to become multi-line as needed while keeping the image inline floated next to it.

I setup an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ubernoob/tYeGR/

If you size the result window you will see that once it hits a small enough width the image will fall below the link.

How can I code this so the link will go to multi-line and leave the image floated next to it?

Comment: For floating the `h3`, bear in mind that floats get screwy if the floated element doesn't have a width set somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `<img>` tag before `<h3>` and remove `float:left` from `<h3>`

I've edited the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tYeGR/7/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried that, it simply places the image above as opposed to below, likewise if I place the image in the H3 its the same result.

Comment: You will need to place it before AND remove "float: left;" on h3 to work. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tYeGR/10/

Comment: @uber_n00b check the jsfiddle link, see if is what you're looking for

Comment: @uber_n00b: It will eventually shift when the container gets narrow enough, as the image is a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

this example works: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/tYeGR/18/ but i changed your floats to absolutely positioning the img's. if that's not good enough, @mediaqueries are the way to go. i tried two in jsfiddle but to no vail. probably user error.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position the images in their rows and then add some padding to the `<h3>` elements so the links don't get covered by the images:

```
.list img {
    position : absolute;
    right    : 10px;
}
.list h3 {
    float      : left;
    font-size  : 12px;
    padding    : 10px 60px 10px 0;/*notice the extra 50px of padding I added to padding-right*/
    min-height : 50px;/*Notice this is added beacuse the image will not dictate height since it is positioned absolutely*/
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to mess around with: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/tYeGR/19/